# How do i read simple json result with jquery and how to post new

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wcf

I built a WCF service which produces JSON. I want to make an external website which uses this webservice. For now I am executing the WCF service over LAN by IIS, so I can connect to the service by going to http://myownaddress/blabla.svc/

I tried to learn some json and to get some results from my service.

For example if I want to use this method:

```
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            UriTemplate = "json/{id}")]
        string JSONData(string id);
```

I'll go to http://myownaddress/blabla.svc/json/123 
And as result I get:
{"JSONDataResult":"You requested product 123"}

Now I have tried to receive this result with the JQuery statement getJSON. But I don't see any results.

My question is how can I get this simple data?

And secondly how can I post data(with javascript) back on to the wcf service is it also possible with json?

-edit-:

I have now updated my code and put this into my document ready function which is located between the `<head> <script>` .... on my page:

```
$.getJSON(
           'http://myownaddress/blabla.svc',
            function(data) 
            {
               alert(data.JSONDataResult);
            });
```

But this won't give the alert with the result. It doesn't even give an alert.. Besides that, in the function I need to give a parameter of id, so for example 123 (look in text above) don't I need to put that in the function also?

Comment: Are you requesting your data within the same domain or is it cross domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get data use `getJSON()`:

```
$.getJSON(
    'http://myownaddress/blabla.svc/',
    function(data) {
        alert(data.JSONDataResult);
    }
);
```

To post data you can use [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/):

```
$.post('http://myownaddress/postservice.svc', function(data) {
  $('.result').html(data);
});
```

or [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (if you need more control):

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

You can also use the ajax for getting the data instead of the `getJSON` method .

**UPDATE:**

try using ajax method as it gives you more control:

```
 $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: "http://myownaddress/blabla.svc/json/123",
      success: function(data){alert(data)},
      dataType: "json",
      complete: function(data){alert(data)},
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){alert(errorThrown)}
    });
```

Also, if you use firefox, check out [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) extension, it will help you greatly.
If you use chrome then use [chrome developer tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview).

Comment: it doesnt return the alert, i have put the .getjson with 'http://myownaddress/blabla.svc/', in the document ready function but it doesn't work, don't i need to instert the parameter id somewhere?

Comment: the "h t t p" is wrong, should be "http" with no spaces. to pass the parameter, you need to add it to the url: "http://myownaddress/blabla.svc/json/123"

Comment: yes i know that.. i did it with spaces so stack won't give me errors

Comment: but it doesn't work either, it wont show anything the only thing what worked was: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ the last example with the flickr, that worked i got the images... but this won't work..

Comment: Did you change the url to contain the id ("http://myownaddress/blabla.svc/json/123")? try using firebug or chrome developer tool to see what is going on.

Comment: it gives me Resource failed to load

Comment: I guess because i have my WCF over IIS and i want to acces it via another computer on the same lan, im accessing its ip address like http://pc222 etc. in the browser i get the json but if i use it with my own webpage i get resource failed to load

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://blabla/RestServiceImpl.svc/json/123. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score 1):

In order for your to get the json data from a WCF service that is outside your website using Jquery you need to use JSONP.

You can perform the call as shown below:

```
$.ajax({
                        url: "http://myownaddress/blabla.svc/",
                        dataType: "jsonp",
                        type: "GET",
                        timeout: 10000,
                        data: null,
                        jsonpCallback: "MyCallback",
                        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {                           
                            alert(action.toLowerCase());
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {alert('error is:' + errorThrown);
                        },
                        complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {alert('complete');
                        }
                    });
```

JSONP is used when you want to perform a cross domain calls using Javascript.

Also your WCF service should be compatible to handle JSONP calls by injecting the results to the response stream using the callBack method specified in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your code like this ?

```
$.getJSON(
    'http://myownaddress/blabla.svc/',
    function(result) {
        alert(result.JSONDataResult);
    }
);
```

Remember `getJSON` will not immediately return you the data, you have to make use of the result in a callback function.

Comment: what do i need to put in function( << )  some people do result some others data?? why do i need to do that

Comment: 'data' or 'result' are just name of a variable, it will contain the data returned from the server. you can name it whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you change your url?

$.getJSON(
           'h t t p://myownaddress/blabla.svc' ==> 'h t t p://myownaddress/blabla.svc/123',
            function(data) 
            {
               alert(data.JSONDataResult);
            });

Comment: What do you mean? my original url is h t t p://myownaddress/blabla.svc but if i want to use the JsonData method then i use h t t p://myownaddress/blabla.svc/json and if i want to pass id = 123 then i do h t t p://myownaddress/blabla.svc/json/123

Comment: You need that url in your $.getJSON method. Else it will return a 404.

Could you check your HTTP status ? using xhr or tools like fiddler?